# Silverstripe 3.4 define and public static

Tags: php, static, silverstripe, public

In Silverstripe 3.4 i get an Error

```
'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Silverstripe/myModule/code/Page.php on line 10'
```

_config.php:

```
define('THIS_MODULE_DIR',  basename(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

Page.php:

```
public static $icon = THIS_MODULE_DIR.'/img/contact-file.gif';  // line 10
```

Please explain why this error occurs / what's i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

PHP before 5.6 doesn't allow expressions for default values. You could use

```
public static $icon = 'my-folder/img/contact-file.gif';
```

But that requires the folder to have a specific name.

You could also set the value in the same file as class, but after the deceleration

```
<?php

class Foo {
  public static $icon;
}

Foo::$icon = THIS_MODULE_DIR.'/img/contact-file.gif';
```

The best alternative though is to upgrade to at least PHP 5.6, especially no earlier version is supported any more.

Comment: Hi! Same error using PHP 5.6. and 7.0;  2nd suggestion without success. i have to use my-folder/... -path.